# Syntax issue with then method on Navigator

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following code snippet:

```dart
_openEditListingDialog(Listing listing,
    Function(Listing) onSubmittedCallback) async {
      Navigator
      .of(context)
      .push(
        new MaterialPageRoute<Listing>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new ListingDialog.edit(listing);
          },
          fullscreenDialog: true,
        ),
      )
      .then((Listing newEntry) {
        if (newEntry != null) {
          newEntry.id = listing.id;
          onSubmittedCallback(newEntry);
        }
      });
  }
```

VSCode complains on the **.then** line with the following error:

```
[dart] The argument type '(Listing) -> Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(Object) -> FutureOr<Null>'.
```

What does this mean and how do I correct this?  I am new to dart and flutter and error messages like this are cryptic for me.  My code is based on this example: https://github.com/MSzalek-Mobile/weight_tracker/blob/v0.4.1/lib/home_page.dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH I'm not sure why VS Code is flagging that as an error for you - I see nothing substantially wrong with it and neither does my VS Code or IntelliJ. I pasted your code in and after adding a Listing class, I had no problem at all (for the record, if you paste enough code that someone can actually run things when you have a problem it makes it a lot easier for them to help you).

And in this particular case, the line number for the error might be quite helpful.

Maybe make sure your VS Code and Flutter are up to date (I'm using the Master channel/branch which has been updated to dart 2.0 so that might be part of it maybe...).

There are a couple of things you could try. First, it seems as though your `push` method isn't picking up the right type - I'm fairly sure the error you're seeing is at the `.then(...` where it expects and Object and you're telling it to be a Listing. You can change your `.push` to `.push<Listing>` to force it to return a Listing.

Next, I'm not actually familiar with what you're doing with Function(Listing). I don't think that's proper dart, or at least any more. I think the recommended way of doing that is typedef-ing a method with the right parameter type i.e. `typedef void ListingCallback(Listing listing);` and then using that as the argument, if you're going to use a callback (see later on in the answer for an arguably better alternative).

The other thing you're doing wrong, which many people seem to do at first in dart/flutter, is mis-using `async`. If you use `async` in a method signature, you should not be using `.then` for futures, but rather using `await`. See [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures) and [this](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-asyncawait-over-using-raw-futures) part of effective dart. I've re-written your code to do that properly:

```
//outside class somewhere
typedef void ListingCallback(Listing listing);

...

  _openEditListingDialog(
      Listing listing, ListingCallback onSubmittedCallback) async {
    Listing newEntry = await Navigator.of(context).push<Listing>(
          new MaterialPageRoute<Listing>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return new ListingDialog.edit(listing);
            },
            fullscreenDialog: true,
          ),
        );

    if (newEntry != null) {
      newEntry.id = listing.id;
      onSubmittedCallback(newEntry);
    }
  }
```

Note that this also gets rid of that whole function that was causing you problems.

Also, you could just use futures and remove the `async` in the method signature, but then you're going to have to make sure to actually return a future.

And lastly, you could (should) probably be returning a Future rather than passing in a callback.

```
  Future<Listing> _openEditListingDialog(Listing listing) async {
    Listing newEntry = await Navigator.of(context).push<Listing>(
          new MaterialPageRoute<Listing>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return new ListingDialog.edit(listing);
            },
            fullscreenDialog: true,
          ),
        );

    if (newEntry != null) {
      newEntry.id = listing.id;
    }

    return newEntry;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @rmtmckenzie.  Your first example worked like a charm and cured my problem.  I didn't have to force push to return a Listing and after moving some line breaks around, the code looks much more readable to me (I come from C# background).

Comment: I am also intrigued by your Future example which would avoid a callback.  I presume then that the result of _openEditListingDialog would be accessed with result = await _openEditListingDialog(...), correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Just make sure that it's safe to make whichever function you're calling it from into an async function - it might not show a syntax error if you change `void initState` to `Future(Void) initState` for example but it will have problems at runtime. (See [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) if you run into that). Note that even if you return a future, you can still use `_openEditListingDialog(...).then((listing) { ..... do whatever })`.

Answer (score -1):

You pass a function

```
Function(Listing) onSubmittedCallback) async {
  // no return here
});
```

This means Dart infers return type `Null`

I think changing it to

```
FutureOr<Null> Function(Listing) onSubmittedCallback) async =>
```

and removing `}` at the end (last line of your code) should fix it.

If you want to keep the function body `{...}` use

```
    FutureOr<Null> Function(Listing) onSubmittedCallback) async {
      await Navigator
      .of(context)
      ...
```

Comment: Changed it but still not good.  I am not sure if I subscribe to your explanation.  The way I understand it, push(Route<T>) should return Future<T> which in this case would be Future<Listing> which should then accept then(dynamic onValue(T value)).

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. Do you get an error message? Which variants of my answer have you tried?

Comment: I don't think the Function(....) has anything to do with the problem he's having.